# Is "$S$ = {$x ∈ l_2$ | $x = (x_n)$, $x_n = 0$ for inﬁnitely many $n$} in $l_2$ " Nowhere Dense?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

$S$ = {$x ∈ l_2$ | $x = (x_n)$, $x_n = 0$ for inﬁnitely many $n$} in $l_2$.

My Try : I think this is a Nowhere Dense Set. I first have shown that the closure of $S$ is $S$ . Then I have shown that $int(S) = \phi$.

Am I correct? If I went wrong anywhere please correct me.

Comment: How did you show the closure of $S$ is $S$?

Comment: In fact, $S$ is dense.  That is, the closure of $S$ is all of $\ell_2$.

Comment: In particular, $S$ contains the subspace of sequences that contain only finitely many non-zero entries; this subspace alone is dense in $\ell_2$.

Comment: Ohh... I got it.... I forgot the set $l_2$. Should I withdraw this question? This seems stupid to me now.@Omnomnomnom

Comment: If you get it now, it might be useful to post an answer to your own question

Answer (score 2):

Actually I got it wrong. My try was wrong. As https://math.stackexchange.com/users/81360/omnomnomnom mentioned closure of $S$ will be whole $l_2$. So this is an Everywhere dense set. 
As an open ball of radius $x>0$ around any sequence in $l_2$  there exists a natural number $K$ such that $\sum_{n = k}^{\infty} x_n^2 < x/2$. So we can say the sequence whose terms are zero from the $k^{th}$ term belongs to that open ball.

Comment: I think you got mixed up between $ S_B=\{ (x_n)_n ;\forall n\in B\;(x_n=0)\}$  for a particular infinite $B\subset \Bbb N$ and $\cup^*S_B $ where the asterisk denotes the union   over all infinite $B\subset \Bbb N.$.

Comment: You can also see that the set of all ($x_n)_n$   such that $x_n=0$ for all but finitely many $n$ and such that every $ x_n$  is rational, is dense and is also countable.